# I'm unsure if I'm misusing the SwitchNavigator or just missing something

Tags: javascript, react-native

I had never used it but upon looking at [the docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html) I saw that I could create a flow.js (in my case: `AuthLoadingScreen.js`) which contains:

```
class ExistingItemsLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const addItems = await AsyncStorage.getItem('addItems');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(addItems ? 'Items' : 'HasItems');//App & Auth
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export { ExistingItemsLoadingScreen }
```

That is tied to my `Items.js` file which is a regular component file that has at the bottom:

```
const AddItems = createStackNavigator({
    Items: { screen: Items },
    ItemsCreation: { screen: ItemsCreation },
    WaitButWhy: {screen: ExplanationScreen},
    Logout: {
      screen: AuthLoadingScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Items',
   }
);
```

My intention would be that you could come to this same route and either have `Items.js` loaded or `HasItems.js` however, I don't know what I need to pass where for this switch to happen.

Currently, if I force `HasItems.js` to create the value by pressing a button which calls:

```
addNewItem = async() => {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('addItems', 'true');
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Items', {hasItems: false});
    };
```

then I get shown the addItems screen but after that, I can't get back to the HasItems and I don't know exactly why.

I think maybe I need to remove the addItems item? I wanted to destroy it but not sure if that's helpful either...

Comment: Now your code doesn't match the stack name at all. And where is the switch navigator?

Answer (score 0):

the way that I have done this is to have a separate screen for handling the navigation logic on startup.

So I will always have the app default to a `startup` screen.
That startup screen will have some kind of animation loader on it while it is making the decision on where to navigate to.

The logic for the navigation can be done in your `componentDidMount` or a `useEffect(() => {}, [])` in the startupScreen.

you can but all the routes in a Switch navigator example:

```
`
    const AddItems = createSwitchNavigator({
            StartupScreen: { screen: startup },
            HomeStack: { screen: home },
            LoginStack: { screen: login }, 
        },
        {
            initialRouteName: 'StartupScreen',
        }
    );
`
```